# selecting/deselecting by clicking in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to select/deselect lines(links) of clicking. But I already have mouseover function it should be different than mouseover, when I select a line that line's color needs to change and it needs to draw a pie chart and deselecting should be available of clicking too.

What I have:

```
    nodeenter.on("mouseover", function(d){ 
console.log(d); 
 d3.select(this).attr("fill", "yellow");

return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible").text("This node's id is: " + d.id + " and " + "Name: " + d.name );})
.on("mousemove", function(){

    return tooltip.style("top",
    (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");})
.on("mouseout", function(d){
    d3.select(this).attr("fill", "rgb(0, 0, " +(d*10) + ")");
    return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});

link.on("mouseover", function(d){
    console.log(d)
     d3.selectAll('.'+d.id).style('stroke','aqua');
    return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible").text("This line's id is: " + d.id + " and " + "Name: " + d.name);})
.on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top",
    (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");})
.on("mouseout", function(d){
     d3.selectAll('.'+d.id).style('stroke','black');
     return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});

//to select
link.on("click", function(d){
  if (!d3.select(this).classed("selected") ){
     d3.select(this).classed("selected", true)
     d3.select(this).style("stroke","red");
  }else{
     d3.select(this).classed("selected", false);
     d3.select(this).style("stroke","black");
  }
});
```

Comment: Upload your code to some platform like fiddle please.

Comment: Sure! Posting soon

Comment: @DavidGuan okay in js fiddle it looks ridiculous. Basically what I want to do is to select a line between two nodes by clicking it and same way to deselect it. Can you help ?

Comment: Is this a force-layout?

Comment: @echonax no, it is not forced and it is 2D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the result: https://jsfiddle.net/xcn35ycm/4/

I binded an on click function to the links.

```
links.on("click", function(d){
  if (!d3.select(this).classed("selected") ){
     d3.select(this).classed("selected", true)
     d3.select(this).transition().attr("stroke","red");
  }else{
     d3.select(this).classed("selected", false);
     d3.select(this).transition().attr("stroke","black");
  }
```

And to update the mouseout function

```
.on("mouseout", function(d){
   if(!d3.select(this).classed("selected") ){
     d3.selectAll('.'+d.id).style('stroke','black');
     return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
   }
});
```

Comment: Looks good to me, I'll try this first thing in the morning! Thank you'!

Comment: It works like mine when I move my mouse away it turns to black

Comment: Are you still keeping the mouseout function where the line goes black again?

Comment: @echanox I am also using mouseover to show; it colors the lines or the nodes when I mouseover them and show me the ID and the name but I put the function you sent me after I close that function. It still is not well. I updated the question with the new code.

Comment: I will ask another question soon can I tag you if you don't mind?